# Is scalar multiple of points of finite order less than 17 always?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

According to the theorem of Mazur (1977),  The torsion subgroup of
the group of rational points $E(Q)$ on an elliptic curve must be one of the following 15 groups:

$C_N$ with $1 ≤ N ≤ 10$ or $N = 12,$

$C_2 × C_{2N}$ with $1 ≤ N ≤ 4$.
In particular, $E(Q)_{tors}$ has order at most 16. **I want to check whether my understanding is correc**t. Let $O$ be the point in infinity.

Does this mean for any point $P \in E(Q)$ of finite order, $m \leq 16$ where $mP=O$?
In other words scalar multiple of points of finite order can't be bigger than 16?

Comment: I think you have the right idea, though not quite correctly phrased. What you get is that for every torsion $P$, if you take *the least* positive $m$ such that $mP=O$, then $m\leq 16$. But of course you can take larger such $m$. For instance, for $P=O$ we could take $m=4619$, and $mP=O$.

Comment: I would replace the word "scalar" with "integer" or eliminate it completely.

Comment: In fact, in the language of Wojowu's comment, one may take $m\leq 12$ - this is the maximal order of any element of any of your listed groups.